# How to add element to empty array

Tags: arrays

I have a button, when I press it will run the program below, but the array always starts from index 0 continuously

```
_check(){
let name = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.name').value
var arr =[]
arr.push(name)
console.log(arr);
```

}

i expect the output ["text","text",...] but the actual output is ["text"]

Comment: find a good book and read about *variable scope*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CinCout mentioned - the issue is that of scope - specifically you are resetting arr back to an empty within the function scope and then pushing the single value into it - meaning it will never have an more that the single value in it.

The solution is to set the array outside the scope of the function and then you will be able to push the value into the array.

```js
    let arr =[];
    
    function _check(){
      let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
      arr.push(name);
      console.log(arr);
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="_check()" class="name" value="test">Click me</button>
```